# How to create a nested menu in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

So I want to achieve the image below but with content sent from server.

[image]

We can [set menu items](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu#menu-example-props)

```
const items = [
  { key: 'editorials', active: true, name: 'Editorials' },
  { key: 'review', name: 'Reviews' },
  { key: 'events', name: 'Upcoming Events' },
]
//...
    <Menu vertical color='black' items={items}>

    </Menu>
```

However, I do not see how to nest them. Just setting item 'content' to some XML.

How do I create a menu with multiple nested sections in `ReactJS\Semantic-UI` in Javacript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the following components:

1. `<MenuContainer />` -> our root component
2. `<Menu></Menu>` -> can render either itself (`<Menu />`) or an `<Item />` component
3. `<Item></Item>` -> can render only a `<li />` or smth

And suppose we have the following JSON coming from our server:

```
{
  label: 'Some menu',
  children: [{ label: 'Sub menu', children: [...] }, ...],
}
```

Let assume that when we find an array in our JSON, that means that we have to render a menu. If we have an object, we render a simple child. A rough algorithm would be:

```
const MenuContainer = ({items}) => ({
   {items.map(item => item.items ? <Menu items={items} /> : <Item data={item} /> }
});
```

Is this something you are looking for?